# Schema-validation: missing sequence [user_sequence]

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, postgresql-9.5

**Error :**

```
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#3e614191': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Micro Focus\Operations Orchestration\central\tomcat\temp\0-oo\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\datamodelContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [user_sequence]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:634)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:448)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1181)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1075)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:513)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:299)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   ... 167 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 | Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in file [C:\Program Files\Micro Focus\Operations Orchestration\central\tomcat\temp\0-oo\WEB-INF\classes\META-INF\spring\datamodelContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [user_sequence]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1634)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:312)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:308)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   ... 175 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 | Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory; nested exception is org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [user_sequence]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:396)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:371)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:336)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1692)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1630)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   ... 182 more
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 | Caused by: org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementException: Schema-validation: missing sequence [user_sequence]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.validateSequence(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:184)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.performValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:100)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.AbstractSchemaValidator.doValidation(AbstractSchemaValidator.java:68)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:191)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:462)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:151)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:360)
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:384)
```

INFO   | jvm 1    | 2020/10/17 23:35:09 |   ... 186 more


**Entity Code**

```
@Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO,generator = "sequence-generator")
    @GenericGenerator(
            name = "sequence-generator",
            strategy = "org.hibernate.id.enhanced.SequenceStyleGenerator",
            parameters = {@Parameter(name = "sequence_name", value = "user_sequence")}
    )
    @Column(name = "ID")
    private Long id;
```

I am stuck here for past 1 days . When I tried to create auto generate it ois giving me error like missing sequence[hibernate_sequence]. So, I generate my own sequence like shown above in **Entity code** part, but I am getting errors again with my custom sequence. I don't know what to do next .

Comment: do you have `user_sequence` table in the database?

Comment: What hibernate version do you use? What hibernate dialect do you use?

Comment: yes , I have hibernate_sequence table .

Comment: Hibernate version : <version>5.2.17.Final</version>